# if statement not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webshop and with jquery i need to check when adding a product if it exists in cart, then it should increase quantity instead of creating a new row.

The code i use to check if it exists in cart is the following:

```
if ($(".store-purchase-list-quantity-plus").attr('part') != SalesNO)
```

If this is true, it should add a new row. If its false it should add quantity.
SalesNO is the product id.

This works only for the first product in cart, then it just keeps adding a new row. It seems to me the if statement only checks the first ".store-purchase-list-quantity-plus", even if there are multiple of them in the DOM.

How do i change my if statement so it checks all .store-purchase-list-quantity-plus" after (attr = salesNO)

Comment: how are you iterating over them??

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: I am agreed to @danmullen that we need to see full code because we can't identify by this way. we want some working fiddle where we can even change code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working exactly as it should. That's just not how you expect it to work.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the *first* element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's `.each()` or `.map()` method.

There are a number of looping constructs available in jQuery, though given your particular need - finding out if there's an element that has a specific attribute value in a set of matched elements - using `.filter()` is probably the best choice.

```
var partExists = $(".store-purchase-list-quantity-plus").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('part') == SalesNO;
}).length > 0; // there's an element with a part attribute matching SalesNO
if(partExists) {
    // increase quantity
}
else {
    // add new entry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are more matches on the page with class `store-purchase-list-quantity-plus`, you will still only select the first with `$(".store-purchase-list-quantity-plus")`. 
Make a loop to check all.